# getting selected index number of column times of a QTableView

Tags: pyqt, pyside, qtableview

I am trying to index of selected row but when I try to do

**1.**

```
indexes = tableview.selectionModel().selection().indexes()
```

indexes will be a list of selected rows total number of column times,

even if I try 
**2**

```
indexes = tableView.selectedIndexes()
```

this too give me the correct indexes selected but total number of column times...

I am just expecting selected row/s in list only once.

Answer (score 2):

If you are selecting the *entire* row, you can do this by changing the [`SelectionBehavior`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionBehavior-enum) of your widget. This will automatically select the entire row, instead of a single cell.

```
self.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
```

After that is set, in your ['itemSelectionChanged'](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged) signal, you need to print the row for each item:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.selection_changed)

def selection_changed(self):
    rows=[idx.row() for idx in self.selectionModel().selectedRows()]
    print(rows)   # or return rows
```

This will return the following for a table that looks like this (with this selection)

[image: Example Table]

Shows a selection of:

```
[1, 2]
```

---

If you do not want to select every column using the `SelectionBehavior`, you need to change your signal a bit. `selectedRows` will only return a row if the *entire* row is selected. If you are selecting individual cells, but still only want the row, change your signal to this:

```
def selection_changed(self):
    rows=[idx.row() for idx in self.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()]
    rows = set(rows)
    print(rows)    # or return rows
```

This changes `selectedRows` to `selectedIndexes`. The important thing that you've noticed is that it will return an entry for every cell selected, even if they are on the same row. The solution to that is the line

```
rows = set(rows)
```

This will return only unique entries. Thus, the same selection as above returns

```
set([1,2])
```

Comment: Hi @Andy I realized I had `tableView.setSelectionBehaviour(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)` due to which row for each column was being returned, I commented it out and all worked fine.